# Error in Block Creation using etc_sendrawTransaction using web3j in polygon-mumbai

Tags: spring, polygon, web3-java

when sending the encoded function in eth_sendRawTransaction is creating failed block creation in polygon. My Contract has Metadata with struct as parameter and in java service sending the meta data as parameters and sending the hexvalue of encoded function too.

Comment: web3j EthereumService using java is :
{
    public String mintNFT(String myId, String uri, NFTMetaData nftMetaData) throws Exception {
        Credentials credentials = Credentials.create(PRIVATE_KEY);
        List<Type> inputParameters = Arrays.asList(
                new Utf8String(titleId), new Utf8String(uri),new Address(CONTRACT_ADDRESS), (nftMetaData.getYear()),//...........10 metdadata
                ));
        Function mintFunction = new Function( "mintNFT", inputParameters, outputParameters );
        String encodedFunction = FunctionEncoder.encode(mintFunction);